# For loop returns None for some iterations

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, nested-loops

I have a nested dict and want to loop through it and append to filters (which is JSON which I will send to BE). Looks like it loops more than it should and that's why there is None value. And it happens only when I split the function into two smaller. Could you please help me understand why is this happening?

Variable

```
${filters_to_add}=    {1: {"sf":'Previous Status', "AND":"", "operatorId": 'in the selection list'},  2: {"sf":'Job Requisition', "AND":"", "operatorId": 'not in the selection list'},
...    3: {"sf":'Job Profile', "AND":"", "operatorId": 'in the selection list', "targetInstances": 'Marketing'},
...    4: {"sf":'Stage', "AND":"", "operatorId": 'not in the selection list', "targetInstances": 'Offer'},
...    5: {"sf":'Candidate', "AND":"", "operatorId": 'is not empty'}, 'Primary Work Location':{"AND":"", "operatorId": 'is empty'},
...    6: {"sf":'Candidate', "AND":"", "operatorId": 'is empty'}}
```

Code which works correctly

```
def _prepare_filters_json(self, pipeline: str, filters_to_add: dict):
        source_fields = self.ssi_get_filter_source_fields(pipeline).json_path("$.data")
        filters = self._get_filters(pipeline)
        for key, value in filters_to_add.items():
            for field_to_add in value.keys():
                new_filter = {"type": 'CONDITION', "id": 'any_id', "field": {}, "operatorId": 'null'}
                if "AND" in value.keys():
                    for source_field in source_fields:
                        if source_field["descriptor"] == value[field_to_add]:
                            new_filter["field"] = source_field
                            new_filter["operatorId"] = value["operatorId"]
                            if "dataType" in value[field_to_add] and source_field["returnType"] == value["dataType"]:
                                new_filter[value["targetType"]] = value["targetValue"]
                            if "targetInstances" in value.keys():
                                new_filter = self._set_filter_comp_oper_value(pipeline, new_filter, source_field["id"],value)
                            if "useValueFromAnotherField" in value.keys():
                                new_filter = self._set_filter_value_from_another_field(pipeline, new_filter,source_field["id"], value)
                            filters["children"].append(dict(new_filter))
        return self._prepare_json(pipelineId=pipeline, filter=filters)
```

And returns correct output

```
{'configurationId': '634d8914d6f4010030bb489b5ed10000',
 'filter': {'children': [{'field': {'descriptor': 'Previous Status',
                                    'id': '228cf38209cb10000fd3509c5c9200a3',
                                    'returnType': 'Single instance'},
                          'id': 'any_id',
                          'operatorId': 'in the selection list',
                          'type': 'CONDITION'},
                         {'field': {'descriptor': 'Job Requisition',
                                    'id': '7b9a3101caaf1000039078f00c56001e',
                                    'returnType': 'Single instance'},
                          'id': 'any_id',
                          'operatorId': 'not in the selection list',
                          'type': 'CONDITION'},
                         {'field': {'descriptor': 'Job Profile',
                                    'id': '7b9a3101caaf100006c9a6dea9d6006f',
                                    'returnType': 'Single instance'},
                          'id': 'any_id',
                          'operatorId': 'in the selection list',
                          'targetInstances': [{'descriptor': 'Marketing',
                                               'id': 'd3bfb62d3bd344c8abf95b8be88d6137'}],
                          'type': 'CONDITION'},
                         {'field': {'descriptor': 'Stage',
                                    'id': 'b6777bdbab7d100022197ed8e03a00b3',
                                    'returnType': 'Single instance'},
                          'id': 'any_id',
                          'operatorId': 'not in the selection list',
                          'targetInstances': [{'descriptor': 'Offer',
                                               'id': '868a8156682541f2aadc2fe90268b75f'}],
                          'type': 'CONDITION'},
                         {'field': {'descriptor': 'Candidate',
                                    'id': 'b6777bdbab7d1000220b76fcba7000b1',
                                    'returnType': 'Single instance'},
                          'id': 'any_id',
                          'operatorId': 'is not empty',
                          'type': 'CONDITION'},
                         {'field': {'descriptor': 'Candidate',
                                    'id': 'b6777bdbab7d1000220b76fcba7000b1',
                                    'returnType': 'Single instance'},
                          'id': 'any_id',
                          'operatorId': 'is empty',
                          'type': 'CONDITION'}],
            'groupCondition': 'AND',
            'id': 'deb03c24-d520-4a60-86ce-2cca38bea3b2',
            'type': 'GROUP'},
 'pipelineId': 'hiring',
 'version': 1}
```

Code which returns None

```
 def _prepare_filters_json(self, pipeline: str, filters_to_add: dict):
        source_fields = self.ssi_get_filter_source_fields(pipeline).json_path("$.data")
        filters = self._get_filters(pipeline)
        for key, value in filters_to_add.items():
            for field_to_add in value.keys():
                new_filter = {"type": 'CONDITION', "id": 'any_id', "field": {}, "operatorId": 'null'}
                if "AND" in value.keys():
                    new_filter = self._set_filter(pipeline, source_fields, new_filter, field_to_add, value)
                    filters["children"].append(dict(new_filter))
        return self._prepare_json(pipelineId=pipeline, filter=filters)

 def _set_filter(self, pipeline, source_fields, new_filter, field_to_add, value):
        for source_field in source_fields:
            if source_field["descriptor"] == value[field_to_add]:
                new_filter["field"] = source_field
                new_filter["operatorId"] = value["operatorId"]
                if "dataType" in value[field_to_add] and source_field["returnType"] == value["dataType"]:
                    new_filter[value["targetType"]] = value["targetValue"]
                if "targetInstances" in value.keys():
                    new_filter = self._set_filter_comp_oper_value(pipeline, new_filter, source_field["id"], value)
                if "useValueFromAnotherField" in value.keys():
                    new_filter = self._set_filter_value_from_another_field(pipeline, new_filter, source_field["id"],value)
                return new_filter
```

Wrong output

```
{'type': 'CONDITION', 'id': 'any_id', 'field': {'id': '228cf38209cb10000fd3509c5c9200a3', 'descriptor': 'Previous Status', 'returnType': 'Single instance'}, 'operatorId': 'in the selection list'}
None
None
{'type': 'CONDITION', 'id': 'any_id', 'field': {'id': '7b9a3101caaf1000039078f00c56001e', 'descriptor': 'Job Requisition', 'returnType': 'Single instance'}, 'operatorId': 'not in the selection list'}
None
None
{'type': 'CONDITION', 'id': 'any_id', 'field': {'id': '7b9a3101caaf100006c9a6dea9d6006f', 'descriptor': 'Job Profile', 'returnType': 'Single instance'}, 'operatorId': 'in the selection list', 'targetInstances': [{'id': 'd3bfb62d3bd344c8abf95b8be88d6137', 'descriptor': 'Marketing'}]}
None
None
None
{'type': 'CONDITION', 'id': 'any_id', 'field': {'id': 'b6777bdbab7d100022197ed8e03a00b3', 'descriptor': 'Stage', 'returnType': 'Single instance'}, 'operatorId': 'not in the selection list', 'targetInstances': [{'id': '868a8156682541f2aadc2fe90268b75f', 'descriptor': 'Offer'}]}
None
None
None
{'type': 'CONDITION', 'id': 'any_id', 'field': {'id': 'b6777bdbab7d1000220b76fcba7000b1', 'descriptor': 'Candidate', 'returnType': 'Single instance'}, 'operatorId': 'is not empty'}
None
None
None
None
{'type': 'CONDITION', 'id': 'any_id', 'field': {'id': 'b6777bdbab7d1000220b76fcba7000b1', 'descriptor': 'Candidate', 'returnType': 'Single instance'}, 'operatorId': 'is empty'}
None
None
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen if a function reaches the end without explicitly `return`ing anything? (If you don't know, please try to look it up.) Now, can you see a way that this might happen in your code? (Hint: what happens if there are no `source_fields` passed to `_set_filter`?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sorry, but I don't get what you mean. If no ```source_fields``` passed to ```_set_filter``` it will show an error that argument is missing.

Comment: No, I mean what if the `source_fields` list is empty?

Comment: What @KarlKnechtel is saying that `_set_filter` returns something only `if source_field["descriptor"] == value[field_to_add]` and only if `source_fields` is iterated at least once (i.e is not an empty list). Also try to simplify your code it is unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example of what is going wrong:

```
def f(ls):
    lx = []
    for x in ls:
        print(f"Element: {x}")
        lx.append(x)
        return lx
    print("Leaving function with `None` value.")

def g(ls):
    lx = []
    for x in ls:
        print(f"Element: {x}")
        lx.append(x)
    return lx
```

Using the REPL, if we:

```
>>> print("Result = {}".format(f([1,2,3])))
Element: 1
Result = [1]
>>> print("Result = {}".format(g([1,2,3])))
Element: 1
Element: 2
Element: 3
Result = [1, 2, 3]
>>> print("Result = {}".format(f([])))
Leaving function with `None` value
Result = None
>>> print("Result = {}".format(g([])))
Result = []
```

What you're doing in your `_set_filter()` function is returning early... but you're also only returning a value IF it's inside the `for` loop. If you pass a list that is empty, nothing is returned at all, because `None` is the default return value.

Note that when you nest an `if` inside a `for`, if every conditional you pass to the `if` returns a `False` value, then any return statement inside the if will never be hit - and this is another way you can have your function end up returning a `None`.

Specifically, your function:

```
def _set_filter(self, pipeline, source_fields, new_filter, field_to_add, value):
    for source_field in source_fields:
        if source_field["descriptor"] == value[field_to_add]:
            ... a bunch of things
            return new_filter  # will return if inside this `if` conditional
        # will move on to the next item in the iteration if the `if` conditional was false.
    # Will return `None` if every element in `source_fields` failed to get inside the `if` conditional (all evaluated to `False`)
    #   or if `source_fields` was an empty list.
```

**Addendum on Dicts**

One trick you might use to simplify your logic is to use the `get()` method on dictionaries.

```
dx = {"a": 1, "b": 2}  # A dictionary
print(dx.get("a"))  # Prints '1'
print(dx.get("c"))  # Prints 'None'
print(dx.get("c", 0)  # Prints '0'
```

Rather than using the indexing built-in, which requires you to do checks before you are retrieving values or risk throwing an exception, this allows you to assign a reasonable result.

Also, you needn't use the `keys()` function in order to test for existence:

```
>>> dx = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
>>> "a" in dx
True
>>> "a" in dx.keys()
True
```

Comment: thanks for explanation. I understood what you mean. But when I move return at the place where it's expected (like you wrote under second #) it shows another error ```TypeError: string indices must be integers``` which means that something is wrong with the loop.

Comment: That is a separate error - but what line did it cite?

Comment: @lily Looking at your input, I think you have a problem with your input. Look on the line with indice `5`.  The value for that index terminates early (a close `}`) and a new index with a non-numeric string value (`Primary Work Location`) starts. That is probably why you're getting a bum iteration.

Comment: the last question. I have a variable as a nested dict because I need to have duplicated keys in json. When it all worked it does not save me the second dict with duplicated name (Candidate in my case). How can I keep both keys?

Comment: @Lily To my knowledge there is no way to do that in a python dictionary. The JSON spec doesn't explicitly disallow this, but most libraries handling it do. You'll probably need to work around it - that said, it's probably worth a separate investigation separate from this question.